# Соотнесение последовательностей двух списков, python

Tags: python, list, dataframe

Пример:

```
set1 = [Apple, Orange, Peach]
set2 = [Orange, Peach, Apple]
```

По итогу мне нужно чтобы set2 содержал такой же порядок как и set1 + должен быть указан старый индекс
Как-то так:

```
set2 = [(2,Apple), (0,Orange), (1,Peach)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Если считать, что элементы списков у вас уникальны, то сделать можно так:

```
set1 = ["Apple", "Orange", "Peach"]
set2 = ["Orange", "Peach", "Apple"]

res = [(set2.index(x), x) for x in set1]
```

res:

```
[(2, 'Apple'), (0, 'Orange'), (1, 'Peach')]
```